# issue getting rack_env with foreman / heroku facebook app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, heroku, foreman

Having a hard time getting my local setup properly.   Trying to run foreman and getting an issue:

```
 web: bundle exec thin -R config.ru start -p $PORT -e ${RACK_ENV:-development}
 RACK_ENV:"FACEBOOK_APP_ID=275479742529226"
 RACK_ENV:"FACEBOOK_SECRET=xxx"
```

running "foreman start"

```
15:21:21 RACK_ENV.1  | process terminated
15:21:21 web.1       | started with pid 23406
15:21:21 system      | sending SIGTERM to all processes
15:21:21 RACK_ENV.1  | started with pid 23407
15:21:21 system      | sending SIGTERM to pid 23406
15:21:21 RACK_ENV.1  | started with pid 23408
 15:21:21 RACK_ENV.1  | /Users/mc/.rvm/gems/ruby-  1.9.2-p290/gems/foreman-          
0.41.0/bin/foreman-runner: line 36: exec: "FACEBOOK_APP_ID=275479742529226": not found
```

apparently I'm setting my fb keys completely incorrect for the env.. if anyone could help out. I've tried setting up a .env file in the root as well, which contain

FACEBOOK_APP_ID=964173273189
FACEBOOK_SECRET=xxx

Removing everything from the procfile (which I believe is incorrect anyways) and running foreman, shouldn't it pickup the .env file in the root by default? which isn't proving any luck.

```
  5:44:20 web.1     | started with pid 23705
  15:44:24 web.1     | missing env vars: please set FACEBOOK_APP_ID and FACEBOOK_SECRET         
  with your app credentials
  15:44:24 web.1     | process terminated
  15:44:24 system    | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

Thanks

Comment: I was able to make some progress by selecting the .env manually by foreman start -e .env -- although curious why this isn't loading by default?   extremely curious as I thought foreman looks for .env in the root by default?

Comment: You should change your FACEBOOK_SECRET -- it's suppose to be secret.  :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think the issue is that foreman isn't finding `.env`, it's that the syntax of your `Procfile` is incorrect. Every line in the Procfile after the `:` should executable on the command line.

Create your `Procfile` with the following contents:

```
web: bundle exec thin -R config.ru start -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV
```

And set your `.env` file to:

```
RACK_ENV=development
FACEBOOK_APP_ID=1234
FACEBOOK_SECRET=xyz
```

Note the `RACK_ENV` var needs to be explicitly set whereas `PORT` does not since Foreman automatically sets it.

Comment: The important tip I got from this was there can be no spaces between the key and '=' and the value.